# Can't enable the location in my app

Tags: ios

I want to find my location in my app. And I `use CoreLocationManager` to get the coordinate, but when I launched the app,it will alert me weather to authorize the location privacy, and after I click the OK button, nothing happened.

Then I open the Settings-Privacy-location in my iPhone, I found my app had not get the location enabled. I turn it on, then I relaunch the app, still nothing happen?

Here is my code:

```
CLLocationManager *locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
[locationManager setDelegate:self];
[locationManager setDesiredAccuracy:kCLLocationAccuracyBest];
[locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray   *)locations
{

}
```

the method `-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray   *)locations` can't run after I set the breakpoint.

Comment: I have solved this problem,locationManager must be an accessors or a member variable.

Answer (score 1):

Put the following code to get your current latitude and longitude in yor device (Not in simulator).

```
CLLocationManager *locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
[locationManager setDelegate:self];
[locationManager setDesiredAccuracy:kCLLocationAccuracyBest];
[locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
CLLocation *location = [locationManager location];
CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate = [location coordinate];
latitude = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%f", coordinate.latitude];
longitude = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%f", coordinate.longitude];
NSLog(@"dLatitude : %@", latitude);
NSLog(@"dLongitude : %@",longitude);
```

Comment: It works,Thank you! And I want to know why it couldn't call the method -(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations  ?

Comment: For call this method you have to set `CLLocationManagerDelegate` n your .h file. It will work for you

Comment: this answer was helpful to you so you may upward and accept it mate